# Where do I start in choosing a speaker?

Tags: amplifiers, speakers

I have just bought a Vox Pathfinder 15R and would like to upgrade the speaker. There's a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPu0k0F-Dm4) where someone has built a new combo using a 12" speaker.

My question is, **where do I start in choosing a speaker**? I know I need to match the impedance, but what about the speaker's power rating? How does this relate to my amp, i.e. how does this affect my choice?

Comment: Also read the second paragraph of [this answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26802/how-to-buy-the-right-power-attenuator-for-a-tube-amplifier/26805#26805), it might be relevant for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the speaker's power rating is > 15W (which is the amp's maximum power) you don't need to worry too much. The main question is if it's really worth to replace the built-in speaker, which - I heard - is actually not bad at all. The only problem is its relatively small size, but due to the combo's size it will be hard to replace it with a much bigger speaker (maybe 10" is feasible, 12" very likely not).

Instead of changing the original speaker, I would recommend to use an external cabinet, which will give you a much bigger sound than you could ever achieve with any other speaker built into the combo. Use a 1x12" or a 2x12" cab and you'll be surprised how this changes your sound. You could take your amp to a store to try this.

Comment: Having looked at google images, it seems there's plenty of space to upgrade the size of the speaker. You might want to open the speaker aperture up a bit to accomodate it though (ie let the sound out as the new speaker = bigger than the old speaker hole). That would involve some tricky woodwork, cutting the speaker hole open without damaging the material over the front. I think Matt's suggestion is more productive of buying a good extension speaker. Maybe VOX make one ?

Comment: Ps. choose a speaker for a guitar amp (not full range speaker) and buy a good quality one eg celestion, which I think were used by Marshall - or another Vox one ? They're not the cheapest on the market but under-purchasing will lead to disappointment - cheaper speakers tend to fail if too much is asked of them, and sometimes have a weedy sound.

Comment: I liked the idea of building a new cab, installing a 12" speaker and all the electronic bits from the original amp. It's mainly because I play regularly in two locations and didn't fancy carrying two units. I don't need 2x12 so a single 12" combo would be perfect.